# Find the smallest positive integer that gives remainder 1 when divided by 2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question states:

> Find The smallest positive integer that gives the remainder 1 when it is divided by each of the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

Any ideas on how to begin?

Comment: The answer is 1.  Maybe you mean second smallest.

Comment: add 1 to their lcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x $ be the number.

The $x -1 $ is a common multiple of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8.  To be the smallest number you somehow have to find the smallest common multiple.  The least common one, if you will.

Comment: Of course, *real* least common multiple is 0.

Comment: The smallest common multiple is 840;After That?

Comment: Well then x - 1 = 840, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes , Then the number would be 841 :)

Comment: Actually, the answer as stated is 1.  841 is the *second* smallest such number.

Comment: But dividing 1 by 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 won't give remainder one , Am I correct ? So It would be the second smallest I guess , Its 841 :) Correct ?

Comment: Of course they will!  $1 = 0*2 +1$.  So the remainder is 1.  1 divided by *anything* has remainder 1.

Answer (score 4):

Call the number you're looking for $x$. Then by definition, $x-1$ is a multiple of $2,3,...,8$. To find the smallest such $x-1$, find the least common multiple of these numbers.

Comment: +1. Maybe you could mention the Chinese Remainder Theorem for a more general method.

Comment: The L.C.M is 840

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem is worth mentioning, I suppose, but if the remainders are all equal, the answer is so simple using the CRT is like killing a fly with a canon.

Comment: Actually as $x \ge 1$ then $x -1 \ge 0$.  $x-1$ need not be the least positive common multiple.  It could be a zero multiple.  The answer as stated *is* 1.